# What is the difference between AnchorPane and Pane in SceneBuilder? And when should I use each?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am new to Scene Builder and it's functions so expect a lot of questions in the coming days regarding it. I am self teaching myself programming of Java and SQL so my only teachers are you guys.

At the moment I am stuck understanding the difference between `AnchorPane` and `Pane` in Scene Builder and when should I use `AnchorPane` and when should I use `Pane`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) extends [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and both are _JavaFX_ containers. _SceneBuilder_ is a tool that generates code. If you wish to learn _JavaFX_, I suggest **not** using _SceneBuilder_. There are many online resources for learning _JavaFX_ which I believe are more appropriate than posting questions to _StackOverflow_.

Comment: As you're learning JavaFX, I suggest reading [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) and the [API documentation (Javadoc)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/). Scene Builder is a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor for [FXML files](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), but note you can build a JavaFX UI without FXML files.

Comment: See also [*Using Built-in Layout Panes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: I had the same question and I found the answer [here on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Anchor-Pane-and-Pane-in-Java-FX).

Answer (score 3):

Check this link on [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Anchor-Pane-and-Pane-in-JavaFX-When-do-I-use-each) about the differences between `AnchorPane` and `Pane`.

As stated there, `AnchorPane` is more flexible and the children of `AnchorPane` can be dynamically resized as it allows the edges of the children nodes to be "anchored" to the edges of the `AnchorPane`. In other words, the child element will 'hold onto' the sides of the `AnchorPane`. `Pane` on the other hand is used when dynamic resizing of the window is not needed.

Be sure to check out this official documentation for [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)